# How to configure Anonymous Share in ADS Security Mode Samba3

Tags: samba

I have samba server where its configured in ADS security mode and it works fine.

I can perfectly able to login with AD user, where system already joined to same Domain.

Now i need to configure a share to public and need to access from non-domain computers with anonymous access.

Need your assistance.

Server details

Samba3-3.2.15-40 on RHEL5.4 32 Bit OS

Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The share needs to have `guest ok = yes`, the [global] section needs `usershare allow guests = yes` and permissions need to be set so `other` can write to that directory.

Comment: That's excellent Thanks for quick answer, Yes after adding i could able to access with anonymously.